# changes make on server not perform on live website?ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have purchase hosting and publish my ASP.NET website, it was working fine from 7-8 months and i change its done,but right now, after publish code and when i update on hosting side in file manager,changes not reflect on live server even i check files on hosting,files changes but not reflect changes on live webpages.

Furthermore i have delete `connection string` from web.config and updated web config, but website working fine even i delete connection string from web.config. It so wired :( :( how its possible, please help me, i am using `PLESK` panel.

Comment: connection string is just use to store connection related information of your database, you can also define it at page level, or not if are not using database.please explain,what are you asking ?

Comment: obviously i am using `database` thats why i am using connection string and on all pages i am getting `database` connection information from web.config. I just said that changes not effect on live application even i delete web.config something stuck on live server? thats why changes not reflect. After delete connection string from webconfig it should show error of database but its not

Comment: This question needs more clarity, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you need any clarity please ask i will let you know, i have provided information in simple words bro

Comment: Delete the entire application and let us know if it carries on working. If it does then the application deleted was not the one running the live site. Iis doesn't cache applications in some otrher place and run them from there but something might have stopped it realizing that code changes have been made and a recompile is necessary

Comment: what do you mean by delete entire application? Is i need to delete all the files from files manager and replace new publish files????or i need to contact hosting provider?

Comment: now i have delete all the files from file manager `httpdocs` but still application working fine and smoothly,lol,what is this??

Comment: @CaiusJard please help !

Comment: *If it carries on working then the application you deleted was not the one running the live site*

Comment: but it was working before 1 week,how it possible???

Comment: @CaiusJard please help

Comment: I can't really give much more help than I have done; you've deleted the entire site, but yet it carries on working. You don't seem to have deleted the right thing - are you connected to a test server?

Comment: no i am connected to live server, i have purchase hosting,using `plesk` panel,1 week ago it working fine and changes done smoothly but now its hangs/freeze